# How can encode bitmap blocks in a multi-threaded fashion?

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, winapi, gdi+

I am trying to to encode a bitmap image block and save it to memory (inside of a vector). It all works fine, until I try to do this in a multi-threaded fashion. I keep getting the following errors:

> Error C2672   'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found

> Error C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept()'

My code is a simple screen-shooting class called inside main(), this is where I try to do multi-threading:

```
bool Screenshot::threadfunc(Gdiplus::Bitmap* bmp, int i, int j, int x, int y, int bw, int bh, std::vector<std::vector< std::vector<BYTE> >> blocksBmpBytesMatrix, std::string dataFormat)
{
    Gdiplus::Bitmap* tile = bmp->Clone(x, y, bw, bh, PixelFormat24bppRGB);

    // write to IStream
    IStream* istream = nullptr;
    CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, TRUE, &istream);

    // define encoding
    CLSID clsid;
    CLSIDFromString(L"{557cf400-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}", &clsid);

    Gdiplus::Status status = tile->Save(istream, &clsid, NULL);
    if (status != Gdiplus::Status::Ok)
        std::wcout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
    return false;

    // get memory handle associated with istream
    HGLOBAL hg = NULL;
    GetHGlobalFromStream(istream, &hg);

    // copy IStream to buffer
    int bufsize = GlobalSize(hg);
    blocksBmpBytesMatrix[i][j].resize(bufsize);

    // lock & unlock memory
    LPVOID pimage = GlobalLock(hg);
    memcpy(&blocksBmpBytesMatrix[i][j][0], pimage, bufsize);
    GlobalUnlock(hg);
    istream->Release();
    return true;
};

bool Screenshot::divideIntoBlocks(HWND chwnd, int screenshotId, RECT rcMonitors, int blockHeight, int blockWidth)
{
    Gdiplus::Bitmap bmp(hbwindow, nullptr);
    int nrows = height / blockHeight + 1 * int((height % blockHeight) != 0);
    int ncols = width / blockWidth + 1 * int((width % blockWidth) != 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
        {
            // compute block coordinates and dimensions
            int x = j * blockWidth;
            int y = i * blockHeight;
            int bw = ((x + blockWidth) > width) * (width % blockWidth) + ((x + blockWidth) <= width) * blockWidth;
            int bh = ((y + blockHeight) > height) * (height % blockHeight) + ((y + blockHeight) <= height) * blockHeight;

            // append to vecs
            blocksInfo.push_back({ i, j, x, y, bw, bh });
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::thread*> pool(nrows * ncols);
    for (auto& ij : blocksInfo)
    {
        std::cout << ij.size() << " : " << ij[0] << "," << ij[1] << "," << ij[2] << "," << ij[3] << "," << ij[4] << "," << ij[5] << std::endl;
        std::thread t(&Screenshot::threadfunc, &bmp, ij[0], ij[1], ij[2], ij[3], ij[4], ij[5], this->blockPngBytesMatrix, "png");
        pool.push_back(&t);
    }
    for (auto& t : pool) { t->join(); }

    return true;
}
```

any idea what am I doing wrong here? or if I can (how can I) do this multi-threading encoding?

Edit: This is Screenshot.h

```
class Screenshot
{
    public:
        // screenshot dimensions and coordinates
        int width, height;
        int screenx, screeny;

        // inti coordinates and dimensions vectors
        std::vector< std::vector<int>> blocksInfo;

        // init data matrices
        std::vector<std::vector< std::vector<BYTE> >> blocksPngBytesMatrix;

        // init screenshot bmp and hbmp 
        HBITMAP hbwindow;
        BITMAPINFOHEADER bi; 

        // init handle for display contexts
        HDC hwindowDC;
        HDC hwindowCompatibleDC;

        // constructor
        Screenshot(RECT, int, int);

        // funcs
        BITMAPINFOHEADER createBitmapHeader(int, int);
        bool capture();
        bool divideIntoBlocks(HWND, int, RECT, int, int);
        bool saveToMemory(Gdiplus::Bitmap*, std::vector<BYTE>&, std::string);
        bool threadfunc(Gdiplus::Bitmap*, int, int, int, int, int, int, std::vector<std::vector< std::vector<BYTE> >>, std::string);

        // deconstructor
        ~Screenshot();
};
```

Comment: What is the type of `blockPngBytesMatrix`?  Also, I'm assuming `threadfunc` is a static member of `Screenshot`?

Comment: `blockPngBytesMatrix` type is `std::vector<std::vector< std::vector<BYTE> >>`.I just added my header for more details.

Comment: Okay, so `threadfunc` isn't a static member and must, therefore, be called against a valid object of type `Screenshot`.  Try `std::thread t(&Screenshot::threadfunc, this, &bmp, ij[0], ij[1], ij[2], ij[3], ij[4], ij[5], this->blockPngBytesMatrix, "png");`.

Comment: This actually compiles, but still results in a `Debug Error!`, causing the program to be aborted :/ `abort() has been called`

Comment: Gdi+ is not thread-safe ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/sec-gdiplus?redirectedfrom=MSDN#thread-synchronization)). Your solution will probably never work.

Comment: @rustyx thank you for the link. that was informative and helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lock inside GDI+ that prevents two threads from using the same Graphics object or the same Bitmap.  Whatever thread gets to it first grabs the lock, the other one will die with an exception.

Refer: [GDI+ objects and multithreading](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/26ac55ee-4763-43e5-971d-dd39e1514ab7/gdi-objects-and-multithreading?forum=netfxbcl)

And [Thread Synchronization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/sec-gdiplus?redirectedfrom=MSDN#thread-synchronization) also pointed out:

> Some GDI+ methods return ObjectBusy if a thread attempts to call a
> method while another thread is executing a method on the same object.
> Do not try to synchronize access to an object based on the ObjectBusy
> return value.

**Instead, each time you access a member or call a method of the object, place the call inside a critical section, or use some other standard synchronization technique.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this helps me a lot narrow down, what I can improve in my code :)